# How does a developer interact with a 3D designer?

Tags: java, 3d, game-engine

A pretty general question here. In the past years I've learned how to code in both college classes and home alone. Mostly classic languages like Java, C, Scala, ...

Recently I thought that it would be nice to realise a small 3D computer game and since I have absolutely no experience in 3D modelling or such, I thought maybe I could try to find someone who knows this field.

But my next thought was that let's say this guy makes a little 3D model for a world and some objects (in Blender or other environment). How am I able to use these models with my background? Can this be done with classical programming languages like Java? Or should I try and get into learn "coding" in a specific game engine that lets me animate and control these models?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: These kinds of question are blatantly off-topic here.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Where should I ask this kind of questions?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @svarog: These kinds of question are blatantly off-topic on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The difficult part about coding a game isn't exporting / importing models, it's drawing something on a screen.

Blender has a [Python API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/) that allows you to export models in any format you like, and also has many standard formats, so you can write a custom system that uses model data.

To draw something without an engine, you'll need to learn to use a graphics API, such as [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) or [DirectX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), depending on your platform.  These interface with Java and C++ fairly well, but are challenging to use themselves.  Graphics programming is very different to classical languages - it's much more about optimisation than design.  It's also a lot less transparent - debugging is not easy.

Game engines have lots of out of the box tools that allow you to spin a game up quickly, without a detailed understanding of graphics programming.  However, they can restrict the game you want to make and your capacity as a software designer.

There are also open source graphics utilities, such as [libGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx), that are worth taking a look at.

In short

- If your aim is to make a game quickly, use a game engine
- If your aim to learn about graphics, try a classical language with graphics programming